# Authenticate HTTP2 session instead of each request

Tags: node.js, http, http2

We are using JSON webtoken to authenticate client access to certain paths in our loadbalancer. The tokens are sent from the client in the cookie header of each request.

Given the persistent nature of HTTP2 sessions I was thinking whether we could just authenticate a session against a path and reduce the overhead of authenticating every request.

Is this a good practice? How can this be done technically? Can the client somehow send the token as session specific data?

Comment: JWT is supposed to be used for stateless auth, so you're supposed to authenticate every request: https://www.jbspeakr.cc/purpose-jwt-stateless-authentication/

Comment: https://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/draft-ietf-httpbis-bcp56bis-04.html#rfc.section.4.10, last paragraph, might be relevant...